# How can I use paste add predictors into a penalized regression argument?

Tags: r, regression, paste

Instead of specifying the predictors as regression arguments, I would like to just pass on a string and change it into the right syntax before it is used for penalized regression. It has been explained in [Loop function to add large numbers of predictors in regression function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477059/loop-function-to-add-large-numbers-of-predictors-in-regression-function?rq=1) or [How to use paste to get formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46003846/how-to-use-paste-to-get-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1) how this can be done for lm but it does not work for penalized regression.

Here is my code:

```
df<-data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-10-01"), by="days"))
df$month<-format(as.Date(df$date), "%m")
df$y<-runif(nrow(df),1,100)
df$time<- -floor(nrow(df)/2):(ceiling(nrow(df)/2)-1)/1000
df$month<-as.factor(df$month)

yname<-"y"
xnames<-colnames(training)
xnames<-xnames[-which(xnames==yname)]
xnames<-xnames[-which(xnames=="date")]
yname<-paste(yname,",")
formula<-paste(yname,"~",paste(xnames,collapse="+"))

ens<-penalized(formula, ~ 0,lambda1=1, lambda2=1, positive =TRUE, data=training)
```

I tried using as.formula for the formula but it does not work with the comma. It is all working fine though if I put the variable names in manually and it is working for lm but not for penalized. Any ideas?

Please note that I have edited the question to make it more specific for penalized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass a vector of variables into lm() formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238038/pass-a-vector-of-variables-into-lm-formula)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, you just need to use the 'paste' function:

```
string <- paste("month", "time", sep = " + ")
```

I am not familiar with the 'penalized' function. However, if you are having further issues you might need to paste the entire formula. For example, for a linear regression, you would need to use something like:

```
string_variables <- paste("month", "time", sep = " + ")
string_formula <- paste("y ~ ", string_variables ,sep = " ")

# simple linear regression usage
ens <- lm(formula = string_formula, data=training)
summary(ens)
```

Comment: Your suggestion works in your setting. However, how do I change it so that I can just specify the vector s=c("month","time") instead of the two strings (in fact I've got a much longer vector and don't want to use a for loop)? string_variables<-paste(string,sep="+") doesn't work, maybe lapply? Moreover, I tried to use string_formula <- paste("y~ ,", string_variables ,sep = " ") for penalized but this does not work although I don't see the difference to lm except of course for the slightly different syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: @Mac: The `lm` function apparently silently coerces strings to R formulas which are language elements. I'm guessing that `penalized` would ahve worked if you had used `as.formula` to do the coercion.